# Не отрисовывается сетка в python turtle

Tags: python, циклы, turtle

Пытаюсь разобраться с модулем turtle питона. Написал фрагмент кода и не могу разобраться, почему не отрисовывается сетка (в виде точек). Судя по дебагеру, циклы будто бы и не выполняются ни разу.
В чём может быть причина?

```
from turtle import *
#tracer(0)
speed('fast')
left(90)
down()
screensize(5000, 5000)
#penup()
c = 30
for x in range(300,10):
    for y in range(300,10):
        goto(x*c, y*c)
        dot(5,'red')

for i in range(10):
    forward(10*c)
    right(80)
    dot(10,'red')
done()
```

Comment: все рисуется... Если речь о первом вложенном цикле, то посмотри где он начинается и где заканчивается. Да, совершенно верно, не выполняется ни разу.

Comment: Посрамился упси